# Node js with local-passport Logout not working

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, express-session

I really don't know why the Post Request and the following redirect and Rendering is not working. Here my Code:

HTML:

```
$(function () {
    $LogOutButton.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/logout"
        });
    });
});
```

APP.js

```
app.get('/login',function (req, res) {

if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.name != "admin") { 

res.redirect('/ImpleniaViewer');
}
else {res.render('Login.hbs');}});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {

res.send("Hallo");

});

app.post('/logout', function (req, res) {
req.session.destroy(function (err) {
res.redirect('/logout'); //Inside a callback… bulletproof!
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `req.logout()` to remove `req.user` from your request local alongside your code.

Your code.

```
app.post("/logout", function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect("/logout");
});
```